# Removing elements from heap

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, heap, heapsort

I made a heap. I am curious if there's something subtley wrong with my remove function:

```
int Heap::remove() {
    if (n == 0)
        exit(1);

    int temp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[--n];
    heapDown(0);
    arr[n] = 0;

    return temp;
}

void Heap::heapDown(int i)
{
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    // comparing parent to left/right child
    // each has an inner if to handle if the first swap causes a second swap
    //  ie    1   ->   3   ->   5
    //      3   5    1   5    1   3

    if (l < n && arr[i] < arr[l])
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[l]);
        heapDown(l);

        if (r < n && arr[i] < arr[r])
        {
            swap(arr[i], arr[r]);
            heapDown(r);
        }
    }
    else if (r < n && arr[i] < arr[r]) 
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[r]);
        heapDown(r);

        if (l < n && arr[i] < arr[l])
        {
            swap(arr[i], arr[l]);
            heapDown(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my output

```
i1i2i3i4i5i6i7
p
Active heap: 7 4 6 1 3 2 5

r
Removed 7
r
Removed 6
p
Active heap: 5 3 4 1 2
```

Here's my teacher's sample output:

```
p
Active heap : 7 4 6 1 3 2 5
r   
Removed 7
r
Removed 6
p
Active heap : 5 4 2 1 3
s
Heapsorted : 1 2 3 4 5
```

While our outputs are completely different, I do seem to hold maxheap principle of having everything left oriented and for all nodes parent > child(in every case I tried). I try to do algs like this from scratch, so maybe I'm just doing something really weird and wrong (I would only consider it "wrong" if it's >O(lg n), as removes are intended to be for heaps). Is there anything in particular "wrong" about my remove? Thanks,

http://ideone.com/PPh4eQ

Comment: +1 on the question. You provided code, your stated goal, what you see is happening, what you think *should* be happening, and your disconnect with the two. The sample code is straight-forward, and though it is not a complete, compilable code base, the core of where you perceived the problem may be is present in entirety and understandable. Thanks for a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I assume you mean besides the fact that you don't need it, since we have an entire heap management function set in the C++ standard library, including make_heap, push_heap, pop_heap, and even sort_heap.

That said, I think I know what your problem is. You have unnecessary movement of elements in your heap. It deals with the swapping algorithm on the heap-down: the same problem is notable on both left and right sides, so I'll show the first one:

```
if (l < n && arr[i] < arr[l])
{
    swap(arr[i], arr[l]);
    heapDown(l);

    if (r < n && arr[i] < arr[r])
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[r]);
        heapDown(r);
    }
}
```

The logic here is not optimal for minimum motion. The "lesser" state of the element being pushed down must fall into one of two basic categories, and different actions are taken for each:

1. The element is not less than *either* left or right. Do nothing.
2. The element is less than *either* left or right, swap only with the *largest*, then drive down into *only* that subtree.

The #2 above in that list is the problem in your code. you swap with the smaller, *then* the larger, if item < left < right. I hope that is clear. If you want a proposal to fix your logic I can provide one, but I think you may have a handle on it if you understand what I described above.

---

**Spoiler**

```
void Heap::heapDown(int i)
{
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    int x = 0;

    if (l < n && arr[i] < arr[l])
    {
        x = l;
        if (r < n && arr[l] < arr[r])
            x = r;
    }

    else if (r < n && arr[i] < arr[r])
        x = r;

    if (x != 0)
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[x]);
        heapDown(x);
    }
}
```

Note:; In case it wasn't obvious, this is the very definition of tail-recursive, and as such could easily be transformed into a simple iterative loop.

Comment: Nice catch. I believe the heap would still remain valid, but it would require more work, since both left and right branches would have to be reordered (whereas heapDown on the larger child can be sufficient as you describe).

Comment: @zennehoy if I'm reading the code right, it *may* swap left and right children if the conditions I mentioned arise, which would be very bad. I'd have to get a whiteboard to know for sure one way or another, but it seems it *may*. If changed to do as I described, I know it should work correctly with minimal motion.

Comment: Yes, yes, I enjoy the stl. Data structures class :)